# Multiple page PDF created by 1 PDF template

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, pdf, itext

Here is my situation, I have a List of data model that will populate a given PDF template into a single big pdf and display on the web page for client to print the file. (no local copy) . I use kuujinbo's example https://stackoverflow.com/a/8525007/5533303 but for some reason i can't let the memory stream to bind when i am going to display the pdf on page. (the error is can't read closed memory stream. ) My system Environment is MVC 5 
with the latest itextsharp.

20151107 Updated:Find the reason. Overall code is correct but at the end of loop i should put  byteInfo = Masterstream.ToArray(); outside the smartcopy using but inside the document using. and create a new memory string later to crab the byteinfo and return to the view.

```
List<Datamodel> PrintList = ( List<Datamodel> )Session["GetDAta"];
         BaseFont baseChineseFont = BaseFont.CreateFont(@"~~~~~~~~~",
            BaseFont.IDENTITY_H,  BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED);
         MemoryStream Masterstream = new MemoryStream();
         byte[] byteInfo;
         using (Document document = new Document())
         {                
             using (PdfSmartCopy copy = new PdfSmartCopy(document, Masterstream))
             {
                 document.Open();
                 foreach (Datamodel childnode in PrintList)
                 {
                     PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(Request.MapPath("~/Content/try 1.pdf"));
                     using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
                     {
                         using (PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(pdfReader, ms))
                         {
                             // do stuff      //
                               AcroFields pdfForm = stamper.AcroFields;
                             #region[input data]

                             pdfForm.AddSubstitutionFont(baseChineseFont);//加font

                             pdfForm.SetField("XXXXXXXX", childnode.XXXXXX);

                             #endregion                                                     
                             stamper.FormFlattening = true;
                         }
                         pdfReader = new PdfReader(ms.ToArray());
                         copy.AddPage(copy.GetImportedPage(pdfReader, 1));

                     }

                 }
                 byteInfo = Masterstream.ToArray();
             }                
         }                         
         Masterstream.Write(byteInfo, 0, byteInfo.Length);
         Masterstream.Position = 0;
         return new FileStreamResult(Masterstream, "application/pdf");
```

correct  result

```
 }///smartcopy end using
byteInfo = Masterstream.ToArray();
         }         //document   end using 
        MemoryStream finalyresult= new  MemoryStream(byteInfo);
        finalyresult.Write(byteInfo, 0, byteInfo.Length);
        finalyresult.Position = 0;
         return new FileStreamResult(finalyresult, "application/pdf");
```

Comment: After finding a satisfying solution for your question, please write up that solution as an answer in its own right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 using (Document document = new Document())
     {                
         using (PdfSmartCopy copy = new PdfSmartCopy(document, Masterstream))
         {
             document.Open();
             foreach (Datamodel childnode in PrintList)
             {
                 PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(Request.MapPath("~/Content/try 1.pdf"));
                 using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
                 {
                     using (PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(pdfReader, ms))
                     {
                         // do stuff      //
                           AcroFields pdfForm = stamper.AcroFields;
                         #region[input data]

                         pdfForm.AddSubstitutionFont(baseChineseFont);//加font

                         pdfForm.SetField("XXXXXXXX", childnode.XXXXXX);

                         #endregion                                                     
                         stamper.FormFlattening = true;
                     }
                     pdfReader = new PdfReader(ms.ToArray());
                     copy.AddPage(copy.GetImportedPage(pdfReader, 1));

                 }

             }
               }///smartcopy end using
           byteInfo = Masterstream.ToArray();
     }         //document   end using 
    MemoryStream finalyresult= new  MemoryStream(byteInfo);
    finalyresult.Write(byteInfo, 0, byteInfo.Length);
    finalyresult.Position = 0;
     return new FileStreamResult(finalyresult, "application/pdf");
```